# Float elements outside the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a slider without using plugins because I cannot find something that full match my requirements...

So, I have a list similar to this:

```
<ul>
  <li><stuff></stuff></li>
  <li><stuff></stuff></li>
  <li><stuff></stuff></li>
  <li><stuff></stuff></li>
</ul>
```

This us is large like the window (width and height) and the `li` inside are `float: left`

The `body` and `html` css is: `width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;`

The problem: if I move the container `ul` ie: to `left: -200px` the second `li` element is not on the left side of the first. It's not floating.

How can I put all my elements to be floated outside the window?

Comment: Provide your whole CSS. Do you use `display: block;` on the `li`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
right: 100%
```

If I understood your question correctly, you don't want anything to show, right? This will work as long as your container starts from the left side of the window.